# Taking array from txt file and setting as constructor arguments in python

Tags: python, arrays, object, constructor, arguments

So I am currently using Classes as part of a project for a course and want to use an array taken from a text file as the arguments. below is what I have tried, can anyone suggest anything to help?

```
class Trips:
    destination = ""
    dep_date = ""
    airline = ""
    ret_date = ""

    def __init__(self, destination, dep_date, airline, ret_date):
        self.destination = destination
        self.dep_date = dep_date
        self.airline = airline
        self.ret_date = ret_date

def get_trips():
    tripsdb = open("tripsdb.txt")
    content = tripsdb.read()
    tripsdb.close()
    trips = content.split("\n")
    trips.pop(len(trips)-1)
    return trips

trips = get_trips()
print(trips)
#this prints ['Lisbon, 28.02.2020, TAP, 03.03.2020', 'Fortaleza, 20.06.2020, TAP, 25.06.2020'] all trips in text file
print(trips[0])
#this prints Lisbon, 28.02.2020, TAP, 03.03.2020 the content of the first array

trip1 = Trips(trips[0])
print(trip1)
#this prints Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class.py", line 25, in <module>
    trip1 = Trips(trips[0])
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'dep_date', 'airline', and 'ret_date'

trip1 = Trips(*trips[0])
print(trip1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "class.py", line 25, in <module>
    trip1 = Trips(*trips[0])
TypeError: __init__() takes 5 positional arguments but 36 were given
```

ultimately what I want it to do is allow the array to become the arguments for Trips.

Comment: `trips` is a list, not an array - in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`trips[0]` is just a string, that's the reason why `*trips[0]` results in 36 arguments (each char). You need to split your string first on `,`.

`Trips(*trips[0].split(','))` should work as expected.

In order to get rid of the whitespaces after the `split(',')`, you can do a:

```
trip_data = [v.strip() for v in trips[0].split(',')]
trip1 = Trips(*trip_data)
```

Comment: Or use the `csv` module to read the file then feed the rows to the class.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I hadn't noticed it had become a string. The split suggestion works perfectly @olisch. I'll check out the csv module too!